# Adding a stock while adding a product

Tags: ubercart

How can I add stocks in [Ubercart](https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart) while adding products?

I insert a new field in the product setting. How can I link the stock with the product?

Comment: plz expand details

Comment: i have added ubercart module in drupal 7 if i want to add stock i can't do at the time of adding new product after adding the new product then i have to edit that product and list the stock details

Comment: I need to stock value to be entered at the time of adding new product can any one help plz...

Comment: Thanks .monymirza.
 finally i find the solution .

After adding the product instead of save click save and continue it will lead to edit page whre we can add stock numbers..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for asking...monymirza.
 finally i find the solution .

After adding the product instead of save click save and continue it will lead to edit page whre we can add stock numbers..

Comment: ok kimlauna...i ll try to ask question like..waht you prefer..

Comment: Actually its not redirecting to stock page also if i click on save and continue also. I am using drupal7. Any suggestions ?